# Binary Buffer Conversion

Tags: c++, networking, binary, buffer, packet

I am writing binary buffers which are byte aligned for network packets that can read/write variant types. It must convert these to into an internal unsigned char (byte) container (STL vector) and then when read back it must reconstruct a variant type from so many bytes.

I have it partially working so far with the following code...

```
var test;
test = buffer_create(100, buffer_grow, 1);
show_message(string(buffer_tell(test)));
buffer_write(test, buffer_u32, 214748);
show_message(string(buffer_tell(test)));
buffer_seek(test, buffer_seek_start, 0);
show_message(string(buffer_read(test, buffer_u32)));
```

And the code that adds these functions in the engine...

http://pastebin.com/Zsz0ifhz

Except the 214748 comes back out as 214528 :( Byte alignment is also not the issue since it is completely ignored for right now, I am just trying to test reading/writing an integer, string writing/reading already works.

Comment: The last byte is being zeroed out for some reason. 214748 (0x0346dc) becomes 214528 (0x034600).

Comment: And the memory layout will depend on your architecture. On x86 it will be layed out: dc 46 03 00.

Comment: Please paste your code here. The pastebin has been removed, so the link is doubly wrong.

Comment: My apologies, I have reposted it, I accidentally set it to 1 hour instead of 1 month.

Comment: If you are able to, try putting a breakpoint on the 8th line of buffer_peak and check if binbuff->ReadByte() is correct, if it isn't correct there's probably something wrong with writing